# Replace contents of text file useing createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have text file named test.txt , I want to replace it with some contents every second.

I tried with below code

```
var fs = require('fs');  

let writer = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt', {flags:'a'});
for(var i = 1;i<=10000;i++)
{
 writer.write('Test '+i); 
}
```

Right now when the above loop is running , its appending like Test 1 Test 2 etc, Instead I want to replace on every write operation , for example after running the above code , result should be Test 10000 inside test.txt .

I tried by changing flags to w like {flags:'w'} , but still not replacing.

Comment: So you are using the `a` (append) flag and wonder why text gets appended? What about reading the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#file-system-flags)?

Comment: I have seen it , but there is no flags to replace , even W is appending.

Comment: `W` is for replacing

Comment: please see the edit , I tried W , its still appending

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to use a filehandle-based implementation instead of using a stream:

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');

async function writeToFile() {
  let writer = await fs.open('test.txt', 'w+');

  for (let i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    await writer.truncate();
    await writer.write('Test ' + i);
  }
  await writer.close();
}
```

This uses [`filehandle.truncate()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandletruncatelen) to clear the file before the next write.

Comment: Thanks :) can i use this with graceful-fs too ?

Comment: @Graciewilliams I have no idea :D